# Getting float=04 out of int=4

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to convert integers into two decimal float numbers. So if i have an integer 3 i want it to be float 03. But if i have an two digit integer 33, i want it to be float 33.

Comment: what is the problem that you are having?... p.s. floats don't have leading zeros except in the case of 0.XX

Comment: I think he wants to zero pad an integer up to two digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float value will always just be the actual number value. If you want to display that value and have to appear with a leading 0, you will have to use [string formatting](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) and the format options to produce `"03"` from a value of `3`.

Comment: Just to give him an example:  `NSString *formatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i", integer];`